# Converter consulta para SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, query, oracle, script, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho a seguinte consulta para o banco da Oracle:

`select xmlagg(xmlelement(e, d.delinha, '').extract('//text()') order by d.nulinha).getclobval()`.

Preciso converter para executar no banco SQLServer, porém não estou conseguindo. Alguém conhece alguma função equivalente ao SQLServer ou outro alternativa para obter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Nunca vi algo parecido em SQL Server, o que exatamente essa Query ai faz?

Comment: Estou conhecendo a query também, aparentemente ela concatena os dados de um xml, vindos do banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se atende, para obter dados de um XML por query no SQL Server:

Exemplo de XML:

```
 DECLARE @myDoc xml 

SET @myDoc = '<log expressao="7085">
<par traduzir="N">André Mariano da Silva</par>
<par traduzir="N">Gestores Boavista</par>
<par formatarData="S">
<par traduzir="N">21/09/2017 09:19:00</par>
</par>
<par traduzir="N">Teste</par>
</log>'  

select  @myDoc.query('(/log/par/par)')
```

Se quiser retornar somente o valor, utilize a função value()

```
SELECT  @myDoc.value('(/log/par/par)[1]', 'varchar(30)')
```

Comment: Cara, valeu pela ajuda, já consigo retornar os valores do xml.